# How to use MlLib with Spark to perform Sentiment Analysis using the Stanford library?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, stanford-nlp, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to access hive tables using SparkSQL. Then will feed to the MlLib of Spark for sentiment analysis. I have check the Stanford NLP library which performs sentiment analysis.

I am current stuck at the usage of MlLib of Spark and the training data with the Stanford NLP to give sentiments in Java. I am trying to give the same output as in the demo: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/sentiment/rntnDemo.html

The output must be a tree structure which I can feed to Tableau tool for visualisation. I need to visualise the data exactly the way it is in the referenced link.

Here is the code for accessing the Hive Table:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class queryhive {

    public static void main(String[] args)
{


    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
            .master("local[*]")
            .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate();
try
{
    Dataset<Row> df = spark.sql("select * from health1 where srno=1");
df.show();
}
catch (Exception AnalysisException)
{
    System.out.print("\nTable is not found\n");
}
}
}
```

Comment: MlLib doesn't give Tableau visualizations. Everything you've asked is completely possible (except that piece, maybe) , so where are you stuck?

Comment: @cricket_007 edited my definition. please check it

Comment: I meant more - "where's your Spark code"? Why does SparkSQL really matter? You can read a plain text as a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 Actually I want to access data use Hive and then input it to the MlLib for analysis. I want to draw sentiments using it. Can you help me? Here is the code for accessing the Hive table.

Comment: MlLib takes a Dataframe, so please put some effort into that code. All I see is a sql statement. Your question may potentially be closed as "too broad"

Comment: ok I will add the `dataset<row>`

Comment: Also, Stanford NLP is not Spark related, so I would suggest you learn how to actually use that before writing more Spark code.

Comment: I know Standford NLP is not related to Spark, But They have a data set of train data on the website. I want to feed it to MlLib for sentiment analysis. Is it doable then please let me know?

Comment: @cricket_007 And what should be the output format to be fed into Tabulaeu, which the program can generate and I use it for visualization?

Comment: Yes, it's doable even without MlLib. It's a pure Spark RDD operation. All you need to do is take some time to "learn NLP sentiment analysis" and `map` the sentiment analyzer over the strings of the Dataset. MlLib is only the "additional" tool to perform machine learning algorithms, which you seem to have no need for at the moment

Comment: And like I said, question is too broad... Forget Tableau in this post and create a separate one asking specifically for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136254/discussion-between-jaffer-wilson-and-cricket-007).